# Could not add private pod as a dependency in other pod?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods, podspec

I am working on a private pod, and when I tried to add it as a dependency to another private pod I am getting this error while running "Pod Update":

```
[!] Error installing EEMyPod
[!] Attempt to read non existent folder `/Volumes/Development/Work/Projects/Pods/eagle-eye-ios-pod/Example/Pods/EEMyPod`.
```

I have no clue why this is happening!

But, while running:

```
pod spec lint
```

I am getting this:

```
Attempt to read non existent folder `/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/EEMyPod`
```

which I think might be a clue.

This is my Podfile:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "EEMypod"
  s.version          = "0.1.0"
  s.summary          = "A short description of EEMypod."
  s.description      = <<-DESC
                       An optional longer description of EEMyPod

                       * Markdown format.
                       * Don't worry about the indent, we strip it!
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = "https://github.com/Codigami/EEMyPod"
  # s.screenshots     = "www.example.com/screenshots_1", "www.example.com/screenshots_2"
  s.license          = 'MIT'
  s.author           = { "Siddarth Chaturvedi" => "Email ID" }
  s.source           = { :git => "git@github.com:Codigami/EEMyPod.git", :tag => "0.1.0" }
  # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/kidsid49'

  s.platform     = :ios, '7.0'
  s.requires_arc = true

  s.source_files = 'Pod/Classes/*.{h,m}'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'AAFNetworking' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
  }

  # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
  # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
  # s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'

end
```

Comment: Yup! This is all about cocoa pods only. I didn't get you?

Comment: Ok,Whats the alternative?

Comment: You might want to post your podfile.

Comment: @Jeff Question is updated with podfile.

Comment: I think right now you are pointing to the master pod repo in your *podfile*, where your private pod does not exist. Follow this guide for how to create your own pod spec repo. http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html

FYI you posted your podspec, not your podfile.

Comment: S.Dependency is added to podspec not podfile as I know..

Comment: @Jeff so in my other pod podspec file I just added this line ->              s.dependency 'EEMyPod', '~> 0.1.0'

Comment: Do you have a repository for your private podspecs? Have you registered it with the cocoapods client tool?

Comment: Yup! I have multiple private pods and working fine. I got mine private Pod spec repo.

Comment: What is the output of this command: ls -1 ~/.cocoapods/repos/

Comment: ios-pod-specs
master -> It prints two repos name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very likely that CocoaPods failed to download the dependency while linting the specification. If you run the command again with `--verbose` it will expose the underlying error from git while cloning the repository. It might be that the tag is missing for the dependency.

CocoaPods 0.35.0.rc2 was changed to provide a better error message (https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2667).

Comment: I used and i am getting detailed one like ->       $ /usr/bin/git clone git@github.com:Codigami/EEMyPod.git
     /private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/EEMyPod --single-branch --depth 1
     --branch 0.1.0
     Cloning into '/private/tmp/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/EEMyPod'...
     warning: Could not find remote branch 0.1.0 to clone.
     fatal: Remote branch 0.1.0 not found in upstream origin

Comment: Why it is considering the version number as branch?

Comment: thats git's internal terminology, there's no differences between a commit, tag and branch. You may have not pushed your tag up.